# How to select all values of a Dropdown using protractor

Tags: typescript, promise, protractor

I have a scenario where there is a element by clicking on which dropdown opens . So i have to select each value of a dropdown one by one. So one value is selected then dropdown gets closed then again needs to open a dropdown and select the second value and so on and after each selection i need to perform some operation.

here is a code which i tried.

```
this.allZoomTimeValues.each((value)=>{  
                  browser.driver.sleep(3000) 
                console.log("1")
                value.getText().then(a=>{
                     console.log("2")
                    this.buttonCross.click().then(function(){
                         console.log("3")
                            browser.driver.sleep(3000).then(function(){
                                 console.log("4")
                                  browser.actions().mouseMove(this.canvas.get(0), {x: 10, y: 80}).click().perform();  
                            })

                    });
                });
            });
```

And so it throws error " **Failed: Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined**

I know this is due to promises but not sure how to resolve promise one by one of the code.
Here is the output which is displayed

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
3
4
F
```

So here all 10 values are returned and for last one all other promises are resolved.

So please help me in how to select each value of a dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because it's a promise, and the loop will run through all values before the 
promise resolver handler is called in the next thread.

try this:

```js
a(0);

function a(index) {
let value = this.allZoomTimeValues[index];
if (!value) {return;}
browser.driver.sleep(3000) 
                value.getText().then(a=>{
                    this.buttonCross.click().then(function(){
                            browser.driver.sleep(3000).then(function(){
                                  browser.actions().mouseMove(this.canvas.get(0), {x: 10, y: 80}).click().perform();  
    a(++index);
                            })

                    });
                });
}
```